# How do I add the FontAwesome icons to an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am not familiar with adding external packages into an ASP .NET MVC project.  How can I add the FontAwesome package?

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/start

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a nuget package. There are a dozen packages listed. The package I recommend is **FontAwesome.MVC** by JiveCode aka JustLikeIcarus.  **NOTE:**  as of 2020-09-16 the package lists in NuGet as 'by Dave Gandy'.

This package takes a dependency on the Font Awesome package containing the CSS and fonts, then it adds a class (FontAwesomeBundleConfig) that registers a style bundle for you.

All that’s left to do is to modify your _Layout, adding the following line of code to your HEAD:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome")
```

Comment: where is it supposed to add the "FontAwesomeBundleConfig" class? I'm not seeing it. Then when I try to add @Styles.Render to my _Layout Head it says The name 'Styles' does not exist in the current context.